# how to do a FOR EACH loop in T-Sql using join?

Tags: sql-server, join

I have a table `PRODUCT` that is basically set up so there is an `PRODUCTID`, `PRODUCTNAME`... it looks sort of like this

```
PRODUCTID  PRODUCTNAME
100        PNAME1   
101        PNAME2         
102        PNAME3
```

Now I have to insert a record into new table `PRODUCTMAPPING` for each row in the `PRODUCT`.

so my new table `PRODUCTMAPPING` should look like this

```
PRODUCTMAPPINGID  PRODUCTID
1                 100
1                 101
1                 102
2                 100
2                 101
2                 102
3                 100
```

and so on ....

I tried doing `while` but I need it using `Join`.

Can we acheive this using joins ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you mapping your product ? What is the relation between these two ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server FOR EACH Loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300414/sql-server-for-each-loop)

Comment: If you have your PRODUCTMAPPINGID values somewhere, you can just cross join that with PRODUCT

Answer (score 1):

One way;

```
select
    row_number() over(partition by a.PRODUCTID order by a.PRODUCTID) PRODUCTMAPPINGID,
    a.PRODUCTID
from PRODUCT a, PRODUCT b
```

Comment: Old style join is not ideal.

Comment: This just seems to be a one off thing

Answer (score 0):

- **Using LOOP**

The following example specifies that the JOIN operation in the query is performed by a LOOP join.

```
Select sp.Name,spqh.quota 
FROM Sales.SalesPersonQuotaHistory AS spqh
    INNER LOOP JOIN Sales.SalesPerson AS sp
    ON spqh.SalesPersonID = sp.SalesPersonID
WHERE sp.SalesYTD > 2500000.00;
GO
```

Refer this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173815.aspx) link

Comment: Sorry to all I changed my Full answer

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT
INTO    dbo.PRODUCTMAPPING
        (
        PRODUCTMAPPINGID
        ,PRODUCTID
        )

SELECT  pmv.PRODUCTMAPPINGID
        ,p.PRODUCTID
FROM    dbo.Product p
CROSS JOIN
        (
        SELECT  pm.ProductMappingID
        FROM    dbo.ProductMappingValues pmv -- WHERE DO THESE COME FROM?
        ) pmv
```