# SQL Export to multiple Excel Worksheets

Tags: sql, excel

everyone!
I'm mostly just curious if this can be done, but here we go:
I have a query I run about once a month that ends up going into an Excel Worksheet. It creates a list of businesses and representatives. Now, I know that you can create SQL code that exports query results directly to a worksheet (see [Export SQL query data to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389637/export-sql-query-data-to-excel)), but I want to know if I can take the result, and export it using SQL to multiple worksheets based on representative? So that each rep gets a worksheet of just their businesses?
I'm thinking it would involve some kind of loop (see [SQL Server FOR EACH Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300414/sql-server-for-each-loop)), but I just can't find anything definitive.
Thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: Consider using Excel VBA or any other programming language (Python, R, C#, Java, Perl, PHP) to connect to database and extract query results with `WHERE` on each rep to worksheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an SSIS package to achieve that. Write a different query for each rep and export the results into an Excel.

Comment: I mean, if I knew the individual reps, sure, but the problem is that I don't know from month to month who the reps are, because they might change. Or are you saying find out who the reps are, then write the queries? Sorry! I should've put that part in my question :/

Comment: Ok I get your point now. So you have different set of representatives each month. I guess what you can do is.- 1. Write a query to find out all the distinct representatives and store the result in a temporary table. 2. Loop through the records in temporary table and run a query with where clause having the rep_id. 3. Save the result in excel file.

Comment: You can also make use of Foreach loop container in the SSIS package.

Comment: Man. I'm an idiot. I didn't even think about storing distinct reps in a temp table. Thanks!

Comment: Not a problem at all.