# SQL Server for loop assistance

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ok so this is my stored proc so far.

```
    ALTER Procedure GetJobInfo()
    AS
    BEGIN
        Select EmployeeId, FirstName, LastName
        From dbo.Employees
        for EmployeeId 
            SELECT ComputerCodeId 
            From dbo.EmployeeJobs 
            Where ComputerCodeId = "F"
    END
```

I need to get the employees which I have done, but then I need to get the employees jobs from the dbo.EmployeeJobs table that match an array of computer codes. How would I go about doing something like that? My end goal is to be able to create a report that breaks the employee jobs into two categories based on the computer code associated with them and then getting the sum of the two categories and having them populate two different columns.

Comment: Provide some sample data, and the expected output.

Comment: Plain TSQL is not suited or designed to produce "reports". Writing reports usually involves some sort of application that is intended for this purpose - even if that app is something like Excel. You should approach this task from the perspective of writing a report using the tool you have chosen rather than from generic tsql.

Comment: I'm using entity framework core 2, end goal is to be able to return everything as a list and then populate reportviewer from said list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not totally sure to understand what you want but you have this two options.

Try to use this option if your table EmployeeJobs contains the column EmployeeId.

**`SELECT EJ.ComputerCodeId , E.EmployeeId, E.FirstName, E.LastName  FROM dbo.EmployeeJobs As EJ INNER JOIN dbo.Employees As E ON EJ.EmployeeId = E.EmployeeId WHERE EJ.ComputerCodeId = 'F'`**

Otherwise if you can't match the EmployeeId you could use the following,  this will filter by the ComputerCodeId and cross by each employee.

**`SELECT EJ.ComputerCodeId , E.EmployeeId, E.FirstName, E.LastName 
    FROM dbo.EmployeeJobs As EJ,  dbo.Employees As E
    WHERE EJ.ComputerCodeId = 'F'`**

Comment: Ok so I've got that in there and It all seems to work fine until I try to get the computer code id. Where dbo.EmployeeJobs.ComputerCodeId = "1" is what it should be but it is saying invalid column name "1" for some reason. The ComputerCodeId will be an int. any clue on how to fix that error?

Comment: Probably is because you are using double quotes instead of singles,  but if you column is int just put 1 without quotes.

Comment: how would I go about setting the Where EJ.ComputerCodeId equal to an array of ints?

Comment: If you want to go through all the values just remove the where clause,  if not you can use WHERE EJ.ComputerCodeId in (1,5,6)

Answer (score 0):

You can try join instead of for loop

```
ALTER Procedure GetJobInfo()
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT EmployeeId, FirstName, LastName
    FROM dbo.Employees E
    INNER JOIN dbo.EmployeeJobs EJ
    ON E.EmployeeId = EJ.EmployeeId
    Where EJ.ComputerCodeId = "F"
END
```

Comment: inner join is not recommended as some of the records will be lost (records containing nulls) and performance can be affected if not indexed well.

Comment: The records can be lost only in case EmployeeId is null. I don't think that any record will be there with null EmployeeId.

Comment: Yes I would always have an EmployeeId. How would I go about making it so the computerCodeId could be equal to an array of computer codes?

Comment: you cannot tell, you can only assume, he did not provide any info regarding EmployeeId. furthermore, if EmployeeId is not indexed well it will impact performance. We cannot guess, we need to work with what we have :)

Comment: This program is for a company with about 20 Employees, they will all have an Id of type INT.

Comment: @brock can you please provide some sample data and expected result?

Comment: Hey @brock if my answer is helpful to you then please vote my answer... :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to look at the [while loop](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/loops/for_loop.php) of sql.

It will provide what you need and is the method to use loops in queries.

***the basic syntax is***:

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;

    WHILE @cnt < cnt_total
    BEGIN
       {...statements...}
       SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
    END
```

***and this example will simulate*** `for loop`:

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;

WHILE @cnt < 10
BEGIN
   PRINT 'Inside simulated FOR LOOP on TechOnTheNet.com';
   SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END;

PRINT 'Done simulated FOR LOOP on TechOnTheNet.com';
GO
```

you can find more info about `WHILE` loop in [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/while-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

investigate and read about it, then give it a shot.

**edit:** for additional method, look at [SQL Server FOR EACH Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300414/sql-server-for-each-loop) post.